# Spell date in Japanese

Tags: code-golf, date, natural-language

## Objective

Given a date, spell it out in Romanized Japanese.

## I/O Format

The input format is flexible. The output format is `<month spelling> <day spelling>`; note the space. You can freely mix cases in output. You may output trailing newline.

## Mapping

### Months

| Month | Spelling |
| --- | --- |
| January | `Ichigatsu` |
| February | `Nigatsu` |
| March | `Sangatsu` |
| April | `Shigatsu` or `Yongatsu` |
| May | `Gogatsu` |
| June | `Rokugatsu` |
| July | `Shichigatsu` or `Nanagatsu` |
| August | `Hachigatsu` |
| September | `Kugatsu` or `Kyuugatsu` |
| October | `Juugatsu` |
| November | `Juuichigatsu` |
| December | `Juunigatsu` |

### Days

Irregular ones are marked *.

| Day | Spelling |
| --- | --- |
| 1st | `Tsuitachi`* |
| 2nd | `Futsuka`* |
| 3rd | `Mikka`* |
| 4th | `Yokka`* |
| 5th | `Itsuka`* |
| 6th | `Muika`* |
| 7th | `Nanoka`* |
| 8th | `Youka`* |
| 9th | `Kokonoka`* |
| 10th | `Tooka`* |
| 11th | `Juuichinichi` |
| 12th | `Juuninichi` |
| 13th | `Juusannichi` |
| 14th | `Juuyokka`* |
| 15th | `Juugonichi` |
| 16th | `Juurokunichi` |
| 17th | `Juunananichi` |
| 18th | `Juuhachinichi` |
| 19th | `Juukyuunichi` |
| 20th | `Hatsuka`* |
| 21st | `Nijuuichinichi` |
| 22nd | `Nijuuninichi` |
| 23rd | `Nijuusannichi` |
| 24th | `Nijuuyokka`* |
| 25th | `Nijuugonichi` |
| 26th | `Nijuurokunichi` |
| 27th | `Nijuunananichi` |
| 28th | `Nijuuhachinichi` |
| 29th | `Nijuukyuunichi` |
| 30th | `Sanjuunichi` |
| 31st | `Sanjuuichinichi` |

## Examples

- May 5th → `Gogatsu Itsuka`
- September 29th → `Kugatsu Nijuukyuunichi` or `Kyuugatsu Nijuukyuunichi`
- October 9th → `Juugatsu Kokonoka`

Comment: What does the pattern look like in the higher "regular" numbers?

Comment: @Someone Since the input is a date, there is no "higher" numbers.

Comment: By "higher," I mean the point in the Japanese numbers where most of them are regular.

Comment: @Someone [Japanese numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals)

Comment: For info, I think Yongatsu Nanagatsu and Kyuugatsu are incorrect spellings.
See for example for april: 
https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%9B%9B%E6%9C%88-517316

Comment: Had to check: Mathematica's builtin `#~DateString~<|"Language"->"Japanese"|>&` does something cool, but not this :}

Comment: Similarly, I believe jyuukunichi is more common.

Comment: @doug Indeed, same for Nijuukunichi, I never heard the forms Juukyuunichi / Nijuukyuunichi be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 148 bytes

```
≔⪪”↶±UH fＸ>¡yüεω!Ln⎇$φＬ¹Kσ⎚FV” ζＮθＦ÷θχjuu§ζθgatsu Ｎη¿››ηχ⁼η²⁰«Ｆ÷η²⁰§ζ÷ηχjuu¿⁼⁴﹪ηχyokka⁺§ζηnichi»«§⪪”↶±‽″÷iπλº⊗wÞαα↓✳C⍘↔ω‖σ?Ｈê⦃¡ＢUQ(Ｕ}⊞▶↔⊙” ﹪η²⁰¿⊖ηka
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFNbsIwEIXX5BQjrxwplUpFV6yQqCoWrZB6Ajcx2LWxiX9QAXH2dGyStNBFFL/xS743M7VgrrZMd93Ce7k19GOvZaAEZC0kGAmeGfB43FpwVkUwzDAQLN2qY4ykAgKkrOBUzouV2cfwHnef3NEW9cY6oCsTlvIgG07bCqaPZQlrJw0ivvBrNF3VIqxMw7/pqYK2HKtky4KPQO7@LVDLDdBXx1lAPbxFBlTw0kamfZJPyCvhXEzuovRX8A9@Y0lp58XkNu8kkXvCrII320RtB/fY3NEqxbKda8/76lpH/xcmMCsxadIkgS5F9p4H4uDsVyLyLPCRIY9/E5PeSQUIA5lFlGlBFisRlFUWj8HacUm/YfNg@maWvHZ8x03gDY52bOGa/9J1z8V01j0c9A8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs in lower case. Explanation:

```
≔⪪”...” ζ
```

Get a list of the base names.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the month number.

```
Ｆ÷θχjuu
```

Print "juu" if it is at least `10`.

```
§ζθgatsu
```

Output the rest of the month name.

```
Ｎη
```

Input the day number.

```
¿››ηχ⁼η²⁰«
```

If it's greater than `10` but not `20`...

```
Ｆ÷η²⁰§ζ÷ηχjuu
```

Output the tens part of the day.

```
¿⁼⁴﹪ηχyokka
```

Print "yokka" if the day ends in `4`, otherwise...

```
⁺§ζηnichi
```

... print the units part of the day.

```
»«§⪪”...” ﹪η²⁰¿⊖ηka
```

Otherwise, look up the root day and append "ka" unless the day is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 236 bytes

Expects `(month)(day)` as integers in \$[1,12]\$ and \$[1,31]\$ respectively.

```javascript
m=>d=>(a="/ichi/ni/san/shi/go/roku/nana/hachi/kyuu/futsu/mik/yok/itsu/mui/nano/you/kokono/too".split`/`,m>9?"juu":"")+a[m%10]+"gatsu "+(d<11?d-1?a[d+8]+"ka":"tsuitachi":d-20?a[d/10^d<20]+"juu"+(d%10-4?a[d%10]+"nichi":"yokka"):"hatsuka")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHdatswFL7vUxwEBQnPkeWusGRxcrMxttDtopdZStXIjlXHOsGWBnmBPUAfcS@SHdkrtKG7EPqk73w/SI/6l@63nT341KEpT1VxaouFKRZcF0zabW2ls7LXTvYEdyg7bIJ02mlZ68g2xxBkFXwfZGsbecRG2uEQbBxDugmywQYJekQ26Q976@/l/bt2MV2yxxDYjDGR6HV7qbJNwnaa5MASbuZKLU2qlnptkg/ENJpGibQ@JrOZSfMsklJld2aeR3G0IyU5pe8jNVo6O8wzKkceYsbqmBHhaYuux3052eOOVxyuRVwCpIQbfYRrX8Of30/wBcdWXwfZxZloKng@HUW35cGX7UPZQT79p12FUfvdUrn4WkMbwA5WdHiLO/NXmYgZg/@Prcfo/mz@7dlhNbwwdXslZj9dmsINOl/3kKZMXFTY8X3poYUC1Efa5rTnBJJEwEtpO/F46zvrdlxMDtp8doZfCUig4q3gSoz/yBkwsc424o3YT/p4FmrGUBNDryI4DzX/D1WCm1ehaiNOfwE)

#### Commented

```javascript
m => d =>                  // m = month, d = day
(                          //
  a = (                    // a[] is a lookup array containing:
    "/ichi/ni/.../kyuu/" + //     0-9: regular prefixes for 0 to 9
    "futsu/mik/.../too"    //   10-18: irregular prefixes for 2nd to 10th
  ).split`/`,              //
  m > 9 ? "juu" : ""       // start with "juu" if m > 9
) +                        //
a[m % 10] +                // append the regular prefix for m
"gatsu " +                 // followed by "gatsu "
(                          //
  d < 11 ?                 // if d is less than 11:
    d - 1 ?                //   if d is not equal to 1:
      a[d + 8] +           //     append the irregular prefix for d
      "ka"                 //     followed by "ka"
    :                      //   else (d = 1):
      "tsuitachi"          //     "1st" is "tsuitachi"
  :                        // else (d > 10):
    d - 20 ?               //   if d is not equal to 20:
      a[d / 10 ^ d < 20] + //     according to the tens digit of d,
                           //     append either "" or "ni" or "san"
      "juu" +              //     followed by "juu"
      (                    //     followed by:
        d % 10 - 4 ?       //       if d mod 10 is not 4:
          a[d % 10] +      //         use the regular prefix for d
          "nichi"          //         followed by "nichi"
        :                  //       else:
          "yokka"          //         use the irregular "yokka"
      )                    //
    :                      //   else (d = 20):
      "hatsuka"            //     "20th" is "hatsuka"
)                          //
```

Comment: Haven't checked if it's shorter, but since mixed case is allowed, maybe something like `'IchiNiSan...'.match(/.[a-z]*/)` is more compact.

Comment: @dingledooper I considered this indeed but I wasn't sure 'mixing cases' was so loose. It would also be ugly, but I guess I can get over that... :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 238 bytes

Takes a month \$ m \in [1, 12] \$ and a day \$ d \in [1, 31] \$ as input, and outputs the Romaji in lowercase.

```python
lambda m,d:m/10*'juu'+O[m%10]+'gatsu '+[O[~d%-20]+1%d*'ka',d/20*O[d/10]+'juu'+[O[d%10]+'nichi','yokka'][d%10==4]][20!=d>10]
O=',ichi,ni,san,shi,go,roku,nana,hachi,kyuu,too,kokono,you,nano,mui,itsu,yok,mik,futsu,tsuitachi,hatsu'.split(',')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJNcuIwEIX3PkVn4RLgzmA7s6LKWWWb4gAeLzyjMQjHEuWfBZtcneluOUbOFAXV7/WT9KnF9Taenc3vTfHr/lF3v3UNHepDt8/SnbpMk0qOZRdnaZWoUz0OE6ikPJafOn7OyctivVNtrVDv83R3LPVekrKOYtovtObP2ShUN9dSthK7KH5WVZmnT4V@pVB0LBRyDK3BobY4UHly2Lt2QlvbGs81d9vbNOHoHLauddbhzUnbYTcZNMRHToudabGZWNHXjLLyzPTqx3D9MOOGYLb3dyigVHyo3EwhEOlSEsSjDiInt5QM91hKkIsQ2EUx9CIu63p1POkvgip6E7zlAtyXO/G4QdEVfeGHSoV59CbjC57MV2ru@bn5muboi5ljfqeZI1Q0jFAuZ/JlXNjhkay2oamEWgYTGjybRcsbzejmO5Q49psOwcRY0EQFcKJXeH7DEFCcNaJYK0g68vKffJBWUdS4HjowFnr6D/3dZAjZy/YQAft65b/k7ENth5Reu9l0CHrrDdLvZQfPkFWQgKJPAm@lFoMSppHQUyGLeRO49saO9PpFrFHTzwHingNxryAG2Rs5LT/p9v4P)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 273 bytes

```
g:m:$``ICHI`NI`SAN`SHI`GO`ROKU`SHICHI`HACHI`KU
d:($``TSUITACHI),($`FUTSU`MIK`YOK`ITSU`MUI`NANO`YOU`KOKONO`TOU`HATSU),\:$`KA
g:g,\:n:$`NICHI
g[4 7]:d[4 7]
g[7]:(-3_g[7]),"A",n
k:(-1_d),1_,/m[-1 2 3],/:\:"JYUU",/:g
k[20]:*|d
j:(,/($``JYUU),/:\:m;k)
f:"gatsu "/{(*x),_1_x}'j@'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwdj1FLwzAUhd/zK2IQ2mwZXbahGF8MgjYGG7DNw+hqI5QFVroXFQbqf/ekLzffOedy701Uk7oOwTyWJlQm1LoKNfDZhTdnfeKUlDpV68mgcnQ3tTdNsriAfPLQ4dXYsHc2mFl4TNOVg+ODddYBG2CpkXJxwEqrSVQReIao0hYS2x297dQwP1DgfLXtE3DBNBNnMsKR/cCF7EUxtStJN3TbiUIdFHvZe8+AkYztZt2pxe9ATioXRTo5hXzum+5HTo6KxY+vz2/Kip98ceGil/3lLzs9ZAR/XMrllcRgSY7Z8J4L4Jqj3tEdvaFS4mpk/ynBVAk=)

I booted earlier versions.  Thanks to @ngn for saving 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>255</s> 235 bytes

`%W()` declares a space-separated array of strings, which is useful for saving bytes over a `split` solution. An empty string interpolation `#{}` is needed to make the first element an empty string.

-3 bytes by incorporating dingledooper's array scheme for storing the special day cases.

```ruby
->m,d{n=%W(#{} ichi ni san yon go roku nana hachi kyuu too kokono you nano mui itsu yok mik futsu tsuitachi hatsu)
'juu'*(m/10)+n[m%10]+"gatsu "+(d==20||d<11?n[~d%-20]+'ka'*(1%d):n[d/10]*(d/20)+'juu'+(d%10==4?'yokka':n[d%10]+'nichi'))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVA9TsMwFN57iqdWUeI2TePAgBChCxMXYIgq5NZOY4KfS2oLRW25CEuE4FCcgUvwEjoxWH7-_uzP75-NX7fdR5l_eVfOr75_5rcmlgfMg4docjiB3lQaUMNeILQWYWuhsbUHFCigEj1bt96DsxZqW1u0JBtoC8Zr0G7vCanB6BpK359oaTc4K0EzG4VP3ofTyCx4ymZYmICnq9l425MwnkUyz7P0eJQ3nC-xeJPBPCM-rAV5eCDZNRaSrKtpJBcZJQxxZKOYPL9chnQ7aXvVEBxi3ylk7HSu3DXqxetGQSiFUyFM4N7vHWizs43TuIXSNuAqBU4RvBbOqaaNAa0DVEoqCRoHvvS4cZo-iUqr53K0o7oQ3VFoguo1ytI0jXnMWZL8w7L4gjOWGLE7lMUjT4xFV8VAkxTt6vzOrvvbfwE)

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 293 bytes

```
/[1-/1@/
/[1/_1/
/[7/sh1/
/[4/shi/
/[9/ku/
/[//
/@/-/
/-/gatsu _/

/_1]/tsuitachi/
/_2]/futsuK/
/_3]/mikK/
/_4]/yokK/
/_5]/itsuK/
/_6]/muiK/
/_7]/nanoK/
/_8]/youK/
/_9]/kokonoK/
/_10]/tooK/
/_20]/hatsuK/

/_1/juu/
/_2/2_1/
/_3/3_1/

/4]/yokK/
/K/ka/
/]/n1/

/0//
/1/ichi/
/2/ni/
/3/san/
/5/go/
/6/roku/
/7/nana/
/8/hachi/
/9/kyuu/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVbNbuM2EEYvPfgpCO5hpaxtWvJ_gAB7anfXaFC0vRSOYHBt2WJkk4ZEJWsYfpJecmkfal-jL9AZUpJFOygQBhFH38x8wxmOSP_1z_6gEyVfvv_47zuSaL3PbxmLc7XlcpN3VbZhzyIVDMa7X43lQkgdZ_sshmdrFa9JvuV5Eude7t-2CIznRGxjktsXHF-L9ZrckTmlbYL_QVSr1iojmghJvB7gbRL6Z7dXuaohIO68F5G7O0IZvdbjyCFoPg9uo1e1X7OYp__L-_DwZmJw16_7YBHmmnQge_LhzgR5I3e8zePXuQ8i3q7eQlmWlXC5sguDjGETLups_LpZvN_yZezdoKHfMlu-VLs9MHj7TG0yvis3DTdziTz0QT_IRu1KM6ArpZp0iR3ht6wRNJZH86XKYnIHbbKNZR3AmkDPFZmsSOxSskJeLKO0orT7qIT0qvY8U4EjP2ByR2Mf3BL6R14IzZeJuKFtA4YA_lTovEh5BfUB-kWkZ2AAwJ-qAQwB-Oz4jNCnEGdgDMA9l-qMTAxLw2cKwEylqmkU9HCRqongsr8UhYBFS3xUeGhx6aJ9i-ZcOvDAwodmFsHQghvlmI4smqm0cPBxGY_DXxOfWDzhlwucWkV6KByiEFP8xJ3yhZjkvXi8TjMMK42baNiv8ItUw0GlcJINhxXsphuOKvwy4XBcR75IOZxUmqukw2mluky7j2n_zuXjBRzUcDP1U6u1U1InTvd69DNoN1g62vbr_vUgoAv2EQRSFx0YtCbAbiwt_LqtPfqzcr1GCP4GtXHhcUm2bPBBv3OHcIJGn_jVoqeIz4racQa1chzxM_BMbzp-QVDC4ooyCEuVbCiginsoIKX070KvO5PvP3xh86DDgo-sBQJbBDiPWZ4YYQCCQGHK0gJnBo-PrAPPDjOsZMFaLXCLmK4OElAuwoit8QyZ4Us_YjuRGnEQMWhCIw4jJiqLEVgUwojjiEFvKSNP0NpaTCOWmpPBvAU9iKesHIKccMuEKgaNY3AWmmwWfdZHocXOwWcs5TBBKKPoYVoBE3bxIZM49Rl8RzAP2UbBNGL4OYAwxvWh94QlZbpQHdgvVpX0HsoLdbaneqfTIbnmmYbDHktfXyBwGuO1ke7a5GmHd4dt767Q8S73GhdLugKLFVrg4e3qcQi5L_QCqNd0fkx3p84xXZ0iWutVocEAv5v5mh6_ncjxadXNcp2Jvff-5r1_ot2teo4zzzfhvmGkp935yszivNhqcDcXDvlQBvQrr_NC1pWtVOanTRnZvVttXSxHu3RoV6a-U7dYrqBqtqwvL3b-Dw)

Newlines are added just for clarity and stripped before execution. Input is expected in `[M-D]` format and is appended at the end of the program since the language does not support any form of input.